# CSS fixed element scrolling impossible

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, fixed, text-alignment

I have a small problem with a text alighnment in Css/html. So, there is a video in the background:

```
<video id="background-video" autoplay loop muted >
<source src="data/videos/cellarb6.mp4" width="1920" height="2000" type="video/mp4" >
</video>
<div id ="cellarground">
<<set $breath to $breath +30>>
 <<audio bup play>>

 breath  <progress @value="$breath" max="100"></progress>
 happiness  <progress @value="$happiness" max="100"></progress>
 credits  <progress @value="$credits" max="100"></progress>



you´ve reached the cellar of the building. 




you look up. 

<img src="data/fotos/holeend.jpeg"  width= "500" height="300">



            another way out. 








                                                 it is getting dark. 
                                                 
                                                 
                                                 
                                                 
                                                 
                                                 
                                                 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[[left]]                                where do you go?                                                     [[right]]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


</div>
```

Infront of the video is the text, but it is not suppose to start at the top of the page. here are the css codes of both elements:

```
#background-video {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
#cellarground {position:fixed; bottom:0px; top:50%; }
```

now there is no scrollbar anymore. if I change the position(absolute/relative), I can scroll the page again. but I need the text to be fixed and the ability to scroll down. otherwise you can´t reach the links.

thank you so much for any help (I´m kinda new to CSS).

Best wishes,
amber

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you shared the whole HTML and CSS source. Is the video player inside the "cellarground" div aswell? Also, i suggest using "%" instead of bruteforcing pixels until you get the text to the center of the screen. This way it'll be at the center regardless of the visitors screen resolution. You can also try "vw" if you're using the "viewport" metatag.

> top: 500px; -> top: 50%;

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer. I´ve edited my question. the problem is  the inability to scroll down the page as soon as I use the position:fixed on the text.